# Responsive secondary and tertiary navigation

Tags: navigation, menu, responsive-design, responsive

I'm working on a responsive Product Customization feature for an e-commerce website that has a hamburger primary nav, but will also need a secondary navigation for selecting the main Customization aspects of the product, and a tertiary navigation for selecting options within the secondary navigation.

Here is the desktop version of the Customization interface

[image]

And here is the current responsive design

[image]

The layout does not translate well to responsive, as the user is swamped with layers of Customization options. I've researched responsive navigation pattern best practices but have come up short.

What's the ideal way to handle having a hamburger primary navigation, as well as secondary navigation, and a tertiary navigation with options directly related to the secondary navigation?

Comment: I am getting a little confused by your question. Are you for multi-level side navigation?

What is the "Customization" interface and why are there secondary and tertiary navigations?

Could you clarify?

Comment: @ShreyasTripathy Yes I am looking for a multi-level side navigation, but the site also has a hamburger primary navigation. The Customization interface is within the product details module, so it has options to select parts of the product to customize, and then different options within those selections. So example: diamond head -> diamond head weight options

Answer (score 1):

I keep sharing this a lot lately, but I think it might work:

https://tympanus.net/Blueprints/MultiLevelMenu/

Comment: Could you copy and paste the relevant information?